# Solve $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{f(\xi)\,d\xi}{( x - \xi )^2 + y^2}$

Tags: integration

I wan t to solve this integral but I am confused how solve
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{f(\xi) \,d\xi}{( x - \xi )^2 + y^2}$ with $y > 0$.
I have the following idea, I am not sure whether it will work or not

1. Break the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{f(\xi) \,d\xi}{( x - \xi )^2 + y^2} + \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{f(\xi) \, d\xi}{( x - \xi )^2 + y^2}$$

2. Make successive transformation to convert the integral into the form

$$\int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{f(\xi _1)\,d\xi_2}{g(x,y)} $$

3. Then use Gauss Quadrature formula to solve the integral.

Is it OK Any suggestion Thanks in Advance

Comment: Without some additional info on $f$ it is quite hard to tell. The integrand might be wildly oscillating on infinity (say, $f(\xi) = \sin(\exp(\xi^2))$, or be very lazy on infinity (say $f(\xi) = |\xi|^{0.99999}$), or be unbounded on infinity, and so on and so for. If you are having a particular $f$ in mind, it would be even better.

Comment: Thanks the function in my example is the followings $f(x) = e{}^{ - \left| x \right|}$ and $f(x) = e{}^{ - {x^2}}$